# Symfony - Neither the property "first_name" nor one of the methods exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView"

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I've been reading and finding a solution for this problem since hours now. But it seems that I can't really fix this error. I found out that only when I add the form in **FOS/UserBundle/Form/Type/RegistrationFormType** that's the only time where it shows in the twig. I think I'm having some problem calling for my **UserBundle/Form/RegistrationFormType**.
Badly need help on this one.

I'm using FOSUserBundle

Here's my **User** class:

```
<?php

namespace UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your first name", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
 */
protected $firstName;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="middle_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your middle name", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
 */
protected $middleName;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your last name", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
 */
protected $lastName;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="position", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your position/title", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
 */
protected $position;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="gender", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please chose your gender", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
 */
protected $gender;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="birth_date", type="string", nullable=true)
 */
protected $birthDate;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
protected $address;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="school", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
protected $school;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="hired_date", type="string", nullable=false)
 */
protected $hiredDate;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="end_date", type="string", nullable=false)
 */
protected $endDate;

// Change the targetEntity path if you want to create the group

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\Group")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="fos_user_user_group",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $groups;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

}

/**
 * @return String
 */
public function getFirstName()
{
    return $this->firstName;
}

/**
 * @return String
 */
public function getMiddleName()
{
    return $this->middleName;
}

/**
 * @return String
 */
public function getLastName()
{
    return $this->lastName;
}

/**
 * @return String
 */
public function getPosition()
{
    return $this->position;
}

/**
 * @return String
 */
public function getGender()
{
    return $this->gender;
}

/**
 * @return String
 */
public function getBirthDate()
{
    return $this->birthDate;
}

/**
 * @return String
 */
public function getAddress()
{
    return $this->address;
}

/**
 * @return String
 */
public function getSchool()
{
    return $this->school;
}

/**
 * @return String
 */
public function getHiredDate()
{
    return $this->hiredDate;
}

/**
 * @return String
 */
public function getEndDate()
{
    return $this->endDate;
}

/**
 * @param String $firstName
 * @return User
 */
public function setFirstName($firstName)
{
    $this->firstName = $firstName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param String $middleName
 * @return User
 */
public function setMiddleName($middleName)
{
    $this->middleName = $middleName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param String $lastName
 * @return User
 */
public function setLastName($lastName)
{
    $this->lastName = $lastName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param String $position
 * @return User
 */
public function setPosition($position)
{
    $this->position = $position;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param String $gender
 * @return User
 */
public function setGender($gender)
{
    $this->gender = $gender;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param String $birthDate
 * @return User
 */
public function setBirthDate($birthDate)
{
    $this->birthDate = $birthDate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param String $address
 * @return User
 */
public function setAddress($address)
{
    $this->address = $address;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param String $school
 * @return User
 */
public function setSchool($school)
{
    $this->school = $school;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param String $hiredDate
 * @return User
 */
public function setHiredDate($hiredDate)
{
    $this->hiredDate = $hiredDate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param String $endDate
 * @return User
 */
public function setEndDate($endDate)
{
    $this->endDate = $endDate;

    return $this;
}
}
```

Here's My **RegistrationFormType**:

```
<?php

namespace UserBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstName', 'text', array('label' => 'form.first_name', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('middleName', 'text', array('label' => 'form.middle_name', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('lastName', 'text', array('label' => 'form.last_name', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('position', 'text', array('label' => 'form.position', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('gender', 'text', array('label' => 'form.gender', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('birthDate', 'date', array('label' => 'form.birth_Date', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('address', 'text', array('label' => 'form.address', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('school', 'text', array('label' => 'form.school', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('hiredDate', 'date', array('label' => 'form.hired_date', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('endDate', 'text', array('label' => 'form.end_date', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
        ;
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'fos_user_registration';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user_registration';
    }
}
```

Here's my **services.yml**:

```
services:
    app.form.registration:
        class: UserBundle\Form\RegistrationFormType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: user_registration }
```

Here's my **config.yml**:

```
fos_user:
db_driver: orm
firewall_name: main
user_class: UserBundle\Entity\User
group:
    group_class: UserBundle\Entity\Group
profile:
    form:
        type: UserBundle\Form\ProfileFormType 
registration:
    form:
        name: user_registration
```

Here's my **twig**: I wanna call all the other entities I made

```
{{ form_widget(form.first_name) }}
{{ form_widget(form.last_name) }}
{{ form_widget(form.middle_name) }}
// and so on...
```

Comment: did the solution cleared your problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

call it like that : `{{ form_widget(form.firstName) }}`

In your form, it's `firstName`, not `first_name`. Same for lastname middlename ...

Comment: This happens when I try to call for the label `{{ 'profile.show.firstName' }}` only shows **form.user.firstName**. I think the problem really is in the form builder. And I'm not sure what it is. I also can not show the `{{ app.user.firstName }}` and all the other new entity.

Comment: what ? that s a total different problem from your previous question ... or you forgot to explain something in your post. you never mentionned `{{ 'profile.show.firstName' }}` or `{{ app.user.firstName }}` ...

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It's the labeling for the forms. Just like `{{ 'profile.show.username'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}` & `{{ 'profile.show.email'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}`. I forgot the trans part. Maybe I just really tired right now. I think I could fix it myself. I've encounter this before.

Comment: Thanks. :)
btw, our boss wants all the other new entity to be accessible in the user edit page only. He want's that only the original `username`, `email`, `password` & `password confirmation` field available in the user registration form. Only after registering the user get's to fill in all the other new entities in the user edit page. Sorry if this is another question from me. I'm making a new question right now with picture for clearer representation of my task.